# Shifting values in an Oracle table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table like this:

| Key | values |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | null |
| 2 | value1 |
| 3 | null |
| 4 | null |
| 5 | null |
| 6 | value2 |
| 7 | null |
| 8 | null |

I need to have a table where every value is shifted down if (and only if) the subsequent cell is null. When I found a different value I keep it and then if I found a new null cell I shift down the new value.

There is a query to do this trick? Thank you.

I want to obtain a table like this:

| Key | values |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | null |
| 2 | value1 |
| 3 | value1 |
| 4 | value1 |
| 5 | value1 |
| 6 | value2 |
| 7 | value2 |
| 8 | value2 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See LAST_VALUE() with IGNORE NULLS: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/LAST_VALUE.html

```
with data(Key, val) as (
    select 1, null from dual union all 
    select 2, 'value1' from dual union all 
    select 3, null from dual union all 
    select 4, null from dual union all 
    select 5, null from dual union all 
    select 6, 'value2' from dual union all 
    select 7, null from dual union all 
    select 8, null from dual -- union all 
)
select key, val, last_value(val) ignore nulls over(order by key ) 
from data
;


1       
2   value1  value1
3           value1
4           value1
5           value1
6   value2  value2
7           value2
8           value2
```

Comment: Sorry, but I think I can't use a last value. Because le last value over a partition is ever the same value (in the example it is "value2"), but i want to insert "value2" only if the first previous value not null is a "value2".